# How do I publish a link to my iChat account

Tags: ichat

So I have an email signature and web site that links to my email, twitter and linkedin identities, how do I add a link to my iChat account (via google talk server) other than just linking to my google user name (which is of course my gmail address). Thanks.

RIP Steve Jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that these work:

```
<a href="aim:goim?screenname=dori">AIM</a> 
<a href="ymsgr:sendIM?dori">YIM</a> 
<a href="gtalk:chat?jid=dori">gTalk</a> 
<a href="skype:dori?chat">Skype</a>
```

Or would, if I had the user account `dori` on any of those services.